# Changes in views.py doesnt appear in my browser unless I stop the server

Tags: python, django

When I make any changes in views.py it doesnt appear in my browser unless I restart the server. Even CTRL + F5 and SHIFT+CTRL+R doesnt work . Does this happen for a reason?

Comment: Do you run the server using `python manage.py runserver` or in a Docker container?

Comment: @DrummerMann yes I do runserver from cmd

Answer (score 0):

While saving the changes you have made in the code does the server restart in the shell. If it does the changes must be displayed otherwise it will not display changes.